# Mongodb async await with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

Developing an app with MongoDB and express.js using the Node.js MongoDB driver(using this driver instead of `Mongoose` for performance). I want use asynchronous function as a more elegant solution for managing my asynchronous code.

I know that if we have no callbacks on `Mongo.client.connect(url)` we return a promise like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res ,next) => {

    let db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/playground');
    db
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch(() => console.log('failure'));

next();
});
```

When we add the async keyword and do also an insert function we now have this:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res ,next) => {

        try{
            var db = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/playground');
            let myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Park Lane 38" };
            await db.db("mydb").collection("customers").insertOne(myobj);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }finally{
            db.close();
        } 

    next();
});
```

### Question

If any `promise` is rejected in the `try` block, will the code in the `catch` block be executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does every database operation method (e.g. findOne, InsertMany, createCollection) of MongoDB driver return a promise when you have no callback?

Yes. This behaviour can be found in the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html) of all these methods.

> If any promise is rejected in the try block, will the code in the catch block be executed?

Only if the rejected promise has been `await`ed in the `try` block.